# Installing scala in windows machine

Tags: scala

I am trying to install scala and I am getting this error. I downloaded the .exe file and executed it. I have created a folder in `C:\Program Files (x86)\scala` and the environemnt path is set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin`. SO when I type scala I get the following error.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin>scala -version
Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_91"=="" was unexpected at this time.
```

Can anyone help me to understand what I might have done wrong?

Thanks and Regards,
Srinivas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of `JAVA_HOME` is set by using quotes,
Set the path without quotes like this:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java
```

Or for folder names like this:

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Progra~1\Java"
```

***Test:***

```
U:\>scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.8 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL

U:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

U:\>set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101"

U:\>scala -version
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101""=="" was unexpected at this time.
U:\>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
U:\>scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.8 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL
```

Comment: Thanks it is because I had my JAVA_HOME as C:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_91